# Flexbox gets outside of its container that is also set to display: flex; at a certain screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have been trying to create a navigation bar and it all goes well except one problem that appear when the window width is between 768px and 922px as the the contents inside the nav element gets outside of its container from the right side .I have tried many solutions, but none of them worked ,and I don't even know the cause of the problem.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test Website</title>
    <!-- font awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3e0066cf06.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <section class="first">

        <div class="container">
            <h1>Test Website</h1>
            <nav>
                <i class="fas fa-bars fa-3x  menu"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="search">
                    <i class="fas fa-search fa-3x"></i>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="content-text">
                <h2> Who are we?</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googl-3eapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');
    *{
        padding: 0%;
        margin: 0%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html{
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-size: 10px;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    ul{
        list-style: none;
        
    }
    
    /* global frameWork */
    
    .container {
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        margin-inline: auto;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 115.59px;
      }
      /* Small */
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .container {
          width: 750px;
        }
      }
     
    
      /* Medium */
      @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .container {
          width: 970px;
        }
      }
      /* Large */
      @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .container {
          min-width: 1170px;
        }
      }
      /* End Global Rules */
      /* Start Components */
    
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
     
      }
    
    .first{
      min-height: 100vh;
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 100%;
      
    }
    .first::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      min-height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3),rgba(0,0,0,.5)),url(images/evgeni-tcherkasski-SHA85I0G8K4-unsplash.jpg);
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .container{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      color: white;
      /* position: relative; */
    }
    
    nav{
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .container::after{ 
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: calc(100% - 30px);
      height: 5px;
      background-color: white;
      left: 15px;
      right: 15px;
      bottom:14px;
    
    }
    
    nav ul{
    
      display: flex;
    
    
    }
    
    nav ul li a{
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 2rem;
      padding: 30px 40px;
      transition: all .2 ease-in-out;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    nav .search{
      color: white;
      width: 50px;
      height: 70px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      position: relative;
      border-left: 3px solid white;
    }
    
    nav .search i{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      right: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul li a.active,
    nav ul li :hover{
      color: #19c8fa;
      border-bottom: 5px solid #19c8fa;
     
      
    }
    
    /* <.........ressponsive Navbar........>>>>>>> */
    @media (min-width: 767px) {
      nav .menu{
        display: none;
      }
      
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      nav ul{
        display: none;
      }
    
      nav ul.clicked{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 20%;
        left: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
      }
    
     
      
    }
    
    .slider{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      background-color:#19c8fa ;
      height: 250px;
      width: 600px;
     
     
      
      
    }
    
    .content-text{
      
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      left: 50px;
    
      
    }
    
    .content-text h2{
      font-size: 3rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-bottom:5px ;
    
    }
    .content-text p{
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      line-height: 20px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    
    
    /* <.........ressponsive Navbar........>>>>>>> */
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean but if you don't want the nav bar to appear at 768px just adjust the media queries directly under your `/* <.........ressponsive Navbar........>>>>>>> */` comment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment . I've found the solution and it's the padding  of <a> tags inside <ul> element as it was supposed to be smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and it's the padding  of  tags inside  element as it was supposed to be smaller.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the flex-wrap: wrap ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your comment . I've found the solution and it's the padding  of <a> tags inside <ul> element as it was supposed to be smaller.